# Master view of multiple dataframes with common columns

Tags: r, dplyr, anti-join

I have three dataframes like below:

```
df3 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','C','E'),col2=c(4,8,2))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','B','C','E','I'),col2=c(4,6,8,2,9))
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','D','C','E','I'),col2=c(4,7,8,2,9))
```

The differences between any two files could be as below:

```
anti_join(df2, df3)
# Joining, by = c("col1", "col2")
#   col1 col2
# 1    B    6
# 2    I    9

anti_join(df3, df2)
# Joining, by = c("col1", "col2")
# [1] col1 col2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

anti_join(df1, df2)
# Joining, by = c("col1", "col2")
#   col1 col2
# 1    D    7

anti_join(df2, df1)
# Joining, by = c("col1", "col2")
#   col1 col2
# 1    B    6
```

I would like to create a master dataframe with all the values in `col1`  and `col2` specific to each dataframe. If there is no such value present, it should populate `NA`.

```
  col1 df1_col2 df2_col2 df3_col2
1    A        4        4        4 
2    B       NA        6       NA  
3    C        8        8        8
4    E        2        2        2 
5    I        9        9       NA
6    D        7       NA       NA
```

The essence of the above output could be established from the above `anti_join` commands. However, it does not provide the complete picture at once. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

*Edit:* For multiple values in `col2` for `col1`, the output is a little messier. For example, `A` has values `4`, `3`.

```
df3 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','C','E'),col2=c(4,8,2))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','A','B','C','E','I'),col2=c(4,3,6,8,2,9))
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c('A','A','D','C','E','I'),col2=c(4,3,7,8,2,9))

lst_of_frames <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
lst_of_frames %>%
  imap(~ rename_at(.x, -1, function(z) paste(.y, z, sep = "_"))) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "col1")
```

It gives the below output.

```
#   col1 df1_col2 df2_col2 df3_col2
# 1    A        4        4        4
# 2    A        4        3        4
# 3    A        3        4        4
# 4    A        3        3        4
# 5    D        7       NA       NA
# 6    C        8        8        8
# 7    E        2        2        2
# 8    I        9        9       NA
# 9    B       NA        6       NA
```

The interesting part of the output is:

```
#   col1 df1_col2 df2_col2 df3_col2
# 1    A        4        4        4
# 2    A        4        3        4
# 3    A        3        4        4
# 4    A        3        3        4
```

whereas the expected output is:

```
#   col1 df1_col2 df2_col2 df3_col2
# 1    A        4        4        4
# 2    A        3        3       NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @tamtam's answer, but a little programmatic if you have a dynamic list of frames.

```r
lst_of_frames <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
# lst_of_frames <- tibble::lst(df1, df2, df3)    # thanks, @user63230
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)  # imap, reduce
lst_of_frames %>%
  imap(~ rename_at(.x, -1, function(z) paste(.y, z, sep = "_"))) %>%
  reduce(full_join, by = "col1")
#   col1 df1_col2 df2_col2 df3_col2
# 1    A        4        4        4
# 2    D        7       NA       NA
# 3    C        8        8        8
# 4    E        2        2        2
# 5    I        9        9       NA
# 6    B       NA        6       NA
```

It's important (for automatically renaming the columns) that the list-of-frames be a *named* list; my assumption was the name of the frame variable `list(df1=df1)`, but it could just as easily be `list(A=df1)` to produce a column named `A_col2` in the end.

Comment: +1, I meant to use `lst` in my comment below! `lst_of_frames <- tibble::lst(df1, df2, df3)` to save having to name the `dfs`

Comment: @r2evans Could you please have a look at my edit? I have updated it with another scenario.

Comment: What you're asking for is outside of the `join` mindset. Because two of your new frames have two `"A"` each, you will get a larger join. See `full_join(df1, df2, by = "col1")` for the problem. With joins, when there are multiple identical keys (`by="col1")`, then it becomes "multiplicative". You will either need to better define how frames join (so as to preempt this), or come up with additional `filter`ing rules (after all joins or after each join) so that this doesn't happen. Since your 4-to-2 row reduction appears somewhat arbitrary, I can't really advise there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helping hand. The idea behind 4-to-2 row reduction is: the combinations of multiple identical keys are avoided and match only them across the datasets. In this case, `A` has multiple values (`4`, `3`) and I do not wish to have a combination of these values in the output. Instead have them only once whether they match with other, otherwise `NA`. I have two values and should result in only two rows. I hope, I am clear here ;)

Comment: The only logic that might work here is a post-join filter, but I don't see the logic that says which of the four possible combinations to keep. The point of your join is to bring in `"col2"`, so you can't use that in the join. What would happen if rows 1-2 of `df2` were swapped? Would the rows you need be the same? (Actually, I don't know that the answer to that question changes my belief: either `merge`/`join` is wrong; or there is more to this that would inform a post-join filter.)

Comment: Even if the 1-2 rows of `df2` are swapped, the output stays the same/similar! Yes, some post-processing is required and I am still processing the logic to achieve that ;)

Comment: @r2evans Should I add this new case as a new question so that others could answer? or unaccept the solution for the same? What is your suggestion?

Comment: I think there are two ways that frames can be combined in a column-wise manner: `merge`/`dplyr::*_join` and `cbind`/`dplyr::bind_cols`. Since you don't want a cartesian expansion, the first is out. Since you have different numbers of each value within the `col1` columns, the second is out. So ... I'm at a loss. I recognize this is likely "toy" data for the sake of the question (thank you), but are there other columns you're not telling us about that are relevant to the joining?

Answer (score 4):

You may use the `full_join` function from the `dplyr` package.

```
df_master <- df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = "col1") %>% 
  full_join(df3, by = "col1") %>% 
  select(col1, df1_col2 = col2.x, 
         df2_col2 = col2.y,
         df3_col2 = col2)

  col1 df1_col2 df2_col2 df3_col2
1    A        4        4        4
2    D        7       NA       NA
3    C        8        8        8
4    E        2        2        2
5    I        9        9       NA
6    B       NA        6       NA
```

Comment: Extending this a little, if one needs to do this for an arbitrary number of frames, then `Reduce(function(a, b) full_join(a, b, by = "col1"), lst_of_frames)` (where `lst_of_frames <- list(df1, df2, df3)` here).

Comment: or `list(df1, df2, df3) %>% 
  reduce(full_join, by = "col1")` too!

Comment: Yup, very little difference between base R's `Reduce` and `purrr::reduce`. The biggest (to me) is bringing in arbitrary arguments, as you showed there.